# Running a ROS node on VxWorks

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have a robot controller that runs VxWorks.  The controller supports the development of C++ applications.  To date, we have been able compile and execute a program on the robot controller that communicates with an external PC via socket connections(not sure of the type).  Can anybody give any insight into what would be required in order to run a ROS node on the robot controller.  I assume there would be some required libraries, but given our success with socket communications, I think there is promise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10316/running-a-ros-node-on-vxworks/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2011-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For basic ROS node capabilities you need to be able to open TCP sockets and communicate with XML-RPC.  Which if you have already achieved socket based communications extending it to run ROS should be possible.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To bind some port you could make use of the basic idea of the [pyoj node](https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/pyoj/src/pyoj.py). This simple node receives a stream UDP on port 10552 and publishes it under a Joy topic. You could adapt the program to publish whatever you want.

It is recommended to read the [Tecnical Overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview).

---

Originally posted by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) with karma: 482 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1